# How to require an object defined by the derived class from within the constructor of a base class

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I want to have a generic class that enforces rules for a derived class like in the template method pattern but I would like to avoid two-phase initialization because I don't want objects to be in a partial invalid state if possible. The base class requires a "Thing" which is also a generic class of something that will be used polymorphically. A seperate factory isn't appropriate because I don't yet know what the derived classes will be.

This is what I came up with using function pointers that the derived class passes down during its construction to its base class so it can have the Thing and this way the derived object can never exist without a valid Thing. I wonder if there is a better way to do this in C++ because this seems pretty hackish?

Edit: corrected for a bit better syntax without function pointers. I think this is the simplest way to do this.

```
class Thing {};

class Base {
public:
    Base(Thing* thing): mustHaveThing(thing) {};
    virtual ~Base() { delete mustHaveThing; };

private:
    Thing* mustHaveThing;
};

class Derived: Base {
public:
    Derived(): Base(createThing()) {};

private:
    static Thing* createThing() {
        return new Thing;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why not instead just have `Base::Base( Thing* thing )` as your only constructor, so your derived will need to do `Derived() : Base( createThing() ).

Comment: Also i would be careful about using new in this way, because then it forces your base class to `delete thing` when it didnt even create it. Instead i would advise using a unique_ptr or have Derived own the thing object somehow.

Comment: @Nonanon Yeah I could do that too, Base is taking ownership of Thing after it gets it I just didn't include the delete in my example.

Comment: Or you could even have a `virtual Thing* thing()` in your base class and relinquish ownership altogether.

Comment: @Nonanon if you mean to call this virtual function from within the constructor of the base class to have the derived class create the Thing that won't work because the derived object is not created yet.

Comment: No i mean instead of owning a pointer to thing, you have the virtual function so that the Base class does not need to create the thing object

Comment: As it seems, you dont need a pointer to a creator function because you only create that `thing` in the constructor and throw away the creator function. In this situation, definitely simpler is  `Base::Base(Thing* thing)` and `Derived::Derived(Thing* thing) : Base(thing) {  }`

Comment: You could also make your pointer a `std::unique_ptr<Thing>` to express the ownership.

Comment: @Nonanon Yeah but what I'm trying to do is enforce any derived class of base to have a Thing (must have a thing after construction) if I leave it to the derived object to create it, it defeats the purpose. Because I will be using the Base class polymorphically those rules need to be enforced.

Comment: @A.S.H the thing doesn't come from the outside it's always the same thing and it's part of the construction of any derived object (but I still need it in the base class as a rule).

Comment: I think it is better now after the edit, but, moreover, the way I see it is that `createThing()` is a static function in the derived. The logic is that it should not depend on the object's state, because the object is not constructed yet, so it may lead to undesirable surprises.

Comment: @A.S.H Ok good point

Comment: `Thing` should have a virtual destructor, and you should be passing around a `unique_ptr` instead of directly calling `new` and `delete`.